# Orbeon Forms - How to use result-dialog

Tags: dialog, orbeon

Can some one please tell me how to use the result dialog mentioned in the 
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/predefined.html#the-result-dialog
I want to know if this is a predefined dialog and if not where exactly I should define it, any coding samples and how to display it when a button is clicked? Where do I need to put the code? Is it in properties-local.xml file?

Please help. Thank you

Comment: I just found out how the `result-dialog` is used. Now I want to know how to customize/change the default message show in it. And how to append the form document ID to this message shown. Also the OK button needs to be navigated to a uri `<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.submit.go.uri-xpath.*.*"
    value="/book/details/link"/>`
did not work can someone please help me to navigate the control to another page when OK button is clicked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't pass the message to be shown to the `result-dialog`. If you just use one of those dialogs, you could [define a property to override](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#overriding-resources) the [default message](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-2017.1-ce/form-runner/jvm/src/main/resources/apps/fr/i18n/resources.xml#L200).
- The value of the [`oxf.fr.detail.submit.go.uri-xpath.*.*` property](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/buttons-and-processes/predefined.html#the-result-dialog) is an XPath expression. If you have a static URL you want to take users to, you can set it to that URL inside single quotes, say `'http://www.orbeon.com/'`.

Comment: Since I want the message to be customized I though of adding `success-message`. Below is how I have added my code `<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save.VIRGINAUSI.*"
   value='require-uploads
   then require-valid
   then save
   then success-message(message="Form has been saved as : http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/VIRGINAUSI/VirginAusiDemoForm/edit/{/form/section-1/docID}")
   recover error-message("database-error")'/>`                        I want to make the string starting from http a hyperlink. Is there any way to do it? Thank you.